# prediction function for classifier using already calculated parameters in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have created a binary classifier using cnn in tensorflow and all the weights calculated for it. Right now it is able to do both training and testing. I need to write a predict function which should take the calculated parameters and one single image and should give the predicted output.

I wrote the following function to do the same, but on running it gives the error:

**Tensor("W1:0", shape=(4, 4, 3, 8), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 3), dtype=float32).**

```
def inferce_prediction(image_data, parameters):
  #X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0, n_C0, n_y)
  Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict_op, tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float")).eval({X: image_data})
    #test_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test})

  print ("test accuracy: ", test_accuracy)
  return parameters
```

You can access the full code using this link: https://github.com/NeonGod314/Keller-asl-classifier-in-core
keller_model_for_sign_classification.ipynb: contains training and function call for predict
dnn_utils.py: contains the predict function

How should i write the predict function or handle this error?